# Why do I get compilation error in this code?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have this code and when I compile it I get compilation error.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    struct Date{
      int day;
      int month;
      int year;
    };

  class appointment{
     public:
       appointment(int d,int m,int y,string n);
     private:
       struct Date date;
       string name;

   };

   int main()
   {
     appointment a(22,12,2019,"James"); 
   } 

   appointment::appointment(int d,int m,int y,string n) :
      date.day(d),date.month(m),date.year(y),name(n)
   {

   }
```

However, when I comment the constructor and use this version of the constructor everything is ok

```
  appointment::appointment(int d,int m,int y,string n) 
//date.day(d),date.month(m),date.year(y),name(n)
{
  date.day=d;
  date.month=m;
  date.year=y;
  name=n;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error, verbatim, in full and directly here as text.

Comment: Initialise all of `date` at once. Not part by part.

Comment: Add info to the question itself, instead of in a comment. That will also allow you to get the appearance right.

Comment: `date` is a perfect candidate for [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Comment: Oh Thanks I initialised all of date at once and it worked, but why this is happening?

Comment: It is happening because your constructor is written differently than language rules allow.

Comment: All members are completely constructed before entering the body of the constructor. The member initializer list provides instructions on how the member is to be initialized. You can assign members of an object in many parts, but initialization of an object is a single transaction.

Comment: `: date{d, m, y}, name(n)` is initialization. `date.day=d;
  date.month=m; ...` is assignment.

Comment: [Some good reading on constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`appointment`'s constructor's member-initialiser can only initialise `appointment`'s own, direct members.

It cannot reach into those members and directly initialise *their* members.

**It has to initialise `date`, not `date`'s members.**

Now, `date` itself has no constructor, but it doesn't need one because you can use *aggregate initialisation* with it:

```
appointment::appointment(int d,int m,int y,string n)
    : date{d, m, y}
    , name(n)
{}
```

You did not encounter the problem with your second attempt, because that did not initialise anything! It merely provided a sequence of assignments (as made possible by the public interface of the `Date` type), and that's fine.

One might argue that this a limitation of the language, but I think it's sensible. You wouldn't want people to only half-initialise your classes. That could lead to inconsistent and unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize objects piece by piece like that.  Instead, use aggregate initialization to initialize your whole `date` member all in one go:

```
appointment::appointment(int d, int m, int y, std::string n)
    : date{d, m, y},
      name{n}
{
}
```